# Aren't non-const variable considered external by default?

Tags: c++, global, extern, linkage

Learning from [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/): *By default, non-const variables declared outside of a block are assumed to be external. However, const variables declared outside of a block are assumed to be internal.*

But if I write this inside `MyTools.h`:

```
#ifndef _TOOLSIPLUG_
#define _TOOLSIPLUG_

typedef struct {
    double LN20;
} S;

S tool;

#endif // !_TOOLSIPLUG_
```

and I include `MyTools.h` 3 times (from 3 different `.cpp`) it says that `tool` is already defined (at linker phase). Only if I change in:

```
extern S tool;
```

works. Isn't external default?

Comment: The your problem is not in the variable,  but in the header file.

Comment: Try to use in begin of the h-file: #pragma once

Comment: I already have Header guard

Comment: @EmbeddedDev `#pragma once` and header include guards only protects against multiple inclusions in the same source file, it has nothing to do with inclusions in different source files.

Comment: Or:  #ifndef MYTOOLS_H
#define MYTOOLS_H
... contents of MyTools.h
#endif /*MYTOOLS_H*/

Comment: Note: (1) Names starting with underscore followed by uppercase, like `_TOOLSIPLU_`, are reserved to the implementation. Effectively the code has UB just because of that. (2) Instead of `typedef struct {} S;`, in C++ just do `struct S{};`. (3) It's generally less hassle and less chance of macro conflict to just use a `#pragma once` as header guard, but unfortunately that's not (yet) officially ISO standard; it's just a *de facto* standard, that all compilers that one would willingly use, supports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration `S tool;` at namespace scope, does declare an `extern` linkage variable. It also defines it. And that's the problem, since you do that in three different translation units: you're saying to the linker that you have *accidentally* named three different global variables, of the same type, the same.

---

One way to achieve the effect you seem to desire, a single global shared variable declared in the header, is to do this:

```
inline auto tool_instance()
    -> S&
{
    static S the_tool;    // One single instance shared in all units.
    return the_tool;
}

static S& tool = tool_instance();
```

The function-accessing-a-local-static is called a Meyers' singleton, after Scott Meyers.

In C++17 and later you can also just declare an `inline` variable.

---

Note that global variables are considered [Evil™](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/big-picture#defn-evil). Quoting [Wikipedia on that issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable#C_and_C.2B.2B):

> **”** The use of global variables makes software harder to read and understand. Since any code anywhere in the program can change the value of the variable at any time, understanding the use of the variable may entail understanding a large portion of the program. Global variables make separating code into reusable libraries more difficult. They can lead to problems of naming because a global variable defined in one file may conflict with the same name used for a global variable in another file (thus causing linking to fail). A local variable of the same name can shield the global variable from access, again leading to harder-to-understand code. The setting of a global variable can create side effects that are hard to locate and predict. The use of global variables makes it more difficult to isolate units of code for purposes of unit testing; thus they can directly contribute to lowering the quality of the code.

<sup>*Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.*</sup>

Comment: I see. But why if I wrote `extern S tool;` in the .h, it doesn't define it, but just declare? Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, `extern S tool` just declares it, and yes, that's guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: Sorry, a typo in the posting now fixed; missing a `&`. :(

Comment: Instead, using `extern const S tool;` inside the .cpp define it, right?

Comment: @paizza: Not sure what you're asking now. But, when you use the `extern` keyword you don't have a definition unless there is explicit initialization. The C++11 standardese is in §3.1/2, “A declaration is a definition unless […] it contains the `extern` specifier (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification 25 (7.5) and neither an initializer nor a function-body […]”

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130702/discussion-between-paizza-and-cheers-and-hth-alf).

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between a **declaration** and a **definition**. `extern int i;` is a declaration: it says that there's a variable named `i` whose type is `int`, and `extern` implies that it will be defined somewhere else. `int i;`, on the other hand, is a definition of the variable `i`. When you write a definition, it tells the compiler to create that variable. If you have definitions of the same variable in more than one source file, you've got multiple definitions, and the compiler (well, in practice, the linker) should complain. That's why putting the **definition** `S tool;` in the header creates problems: each source file that #include's that header ends up **defining** `tool`, and the compiler rightly complains.

The difference between a `const` and a not-`const` definition is, as you say, that `const int i = 3;` defines a variable named `i` that is **local** to the file being compiled. There's no problem having the same definition in more than one source file, because those guys all have **internal linkage**, that is, they aren't visible outside the source file. When you don't have the `const`, for example, with `int i = 3;`, that also defines a variable named `i`, but it has **external linkage**, that it, it's visible outside the source file, and having the same definition in multiple files gives you that error. (technically, it's definitions of the **same name** that lead to problems; `int i = 3;` and `double i = 3.0;` in two different source files still are duplicate definitions).

Answer (score 2):

> By default, non-const variables declared outside of a block are assumed to be external. However, const variables declared outside of a block are assumed to be internal.

That statement is still correct in your case.

In your `MyTools.h`, `tool` is external.

```
S tool; // define tool, external scope
```

In your `cpp` file, however, the `extern` keyword merely means that `S` is defined else where.

```
extern S tool; // declare tool
```